# UIbezierpath drawing with animation

Tags: ios, ipad, core-animation, core-graphics, uibezierpath

I need some suggestions regarding my one specific ipad project.In this project i have subclass of `UIview`  and there i have dawn several circles overriding `drawRect` method. Now i have also some semi rectangular `UIbezierpath` shape which need to be drawn with animation after i touch the circle. I was wondering what would be the easy way to draw this  `UIbezierpath` shape with animation.Do I need use 'NStimer' or call `setneedsdisplay` after touch each times.A help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: why do you want to use NSTimer..? do you want it respond after some time when you touch it..?

Comment: No. i was just thinking to to draw 4 `UIbezierpath` shapes around circle repeatedly. what could be the efficient way?

Comment: Never use a NSTimer for animations. Use a CADisplayLink instead.

Comment: I suggest that you read [this article about animating paths in shape layers](http://blog.pixelingene.com/2012/02/animating-pie-slices-using-a-custom-calayer/)